# Forced to allow automatic updates?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate, oxygenos, oneplus-5

So I wanted to stop the Play Store from automatically updating only to find that this is literally not an option.

My version of Play Store is 8.1.73 and when in settings I press the "auto-update" fields I get the option to update over wi-fi or also over data.
What happened here? Did Google just sneakily remove the option to not auto-update? Is it a OnePlus "feature"?

I have a OnePlus 5 with the latest update for Oxygen OS for my region (Europe) installed.

Comment: Not my case. The Play Store on my OnePlus 5 gives three options: the two identical to you, and another "Don't update apps automatically".

Answer (score 0):

Check out in the settings tab of google play store, there you'll find 'Auto Update Apps. There are three options,
Do not auto-update apps,
Auto-update apps at any time. Data charges may apply,
Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only.
So you can make auto update off.